# Translating "for", as in "with"

Tags: translation

In mathematics, when we introduce variables in expressions we might say, for example, "F=ma, for m the mass and a the acceleration." How would you translate the "for" here? Equivalently we could say "with m the mass...".

I was considering 以 or 为, with "F=ma,以质量m..." or "F=ma,质量为m...". If neither of these is appropriate, what is appropriate here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'for' in your sentence functions more like 'about' than 'with'.

> F=ma

> **for** 'm' the mass and (**for**) 'a' the acceleration = about 'm', it refers to mass; about 'a', it refers to 'the acceleration'

> 至于'm', 指的是质量, 至于'a', 指的是加速度 --> 'm', 指的是质量, 'a' 指的是加速度 (omit 至于 in this sentence make it sound more natural in Chinese)

If you want to use 'with' instead, your sentence would become

> F=ma

> **with** 'm' (as) the mass and **with** 'a' (as) the acceleration

> **以**'m'(为)质量, **以**'a'(为)加速度

I think the sentence below is easier to translate

> F=ma

> 'm' **represents** the mass and 'a' **represents** the acceleration

> 'm' **代表**质量，'a' **代表**加速度

Answer (score 0):

"F=ma, for m the mass and a the acceleration."

F = ma, **在其中** 'm' 是质量，'a' 是加速度.